# TypeScript function implementation downgrades parameter types to `any` if you declare a param type

Tags: typescript

I have a function interface like this:

```
interface Callback {
  (a: string, b: number): void;
}
```

And I can implement it without declaring parameter types like this:

```
const callback: Callback = (a, b) => { }
```

In this case TypeScript understands the parameter types of `callback` are actually `(a: string, b: number)`.

However, if I declare it with one parameter typed, such as `b: number`:

```
const callback: Callback = (a, b: number) => { }
```

The other parameter `a`'s type becomes `any`. [Example in the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Callback%20%7B%0A%20%20(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20number)%3A%20void%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20callback%3A%20Callback%20%3D%20(a%2C%20b)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Result%3A%20(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20number)%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20callback2%3A%20Callback%20%3D%20(a%2C%20b%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Result%3A%20(a%3A%20any%2C%20b%3A%20number)%0A%7D). What's odd is that the compiler does know what type `a` should be, because it won't let you define it wrongly, for example `(a: boolean, b: number)` will say the parameters are incompatible. Why won't it infer the parameter type of `a`?

---

The above is a trivial example, but it's giving me some headache when trying to generate a type-safe [Redux reducer map](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ReducingBoilerplate.html#generating-reducers):

```
interface IReducer<TState> {
  (state: TState, action: IAction): TState;
}

interface IReducerMap<TState> {
  [actionType: string]: IReducer<TState>;
}

interface MyState { hello: string; }

interface MyAction extends IAction { say: string; }

const myReducerMap: IReducerMap<MyState> = {
  // Result: `(state: MyState, action: IAction) => MyState`
  // But I get an error on `action.say` not defined in `IAction`
  reducer1: (state, action) => {
    return { hello: action.say };
  },

  // Result: `(state: any, action: MyAction) => computed`
  reducer2: (state, action: MyAction) => {
    return { hello: action.say + state.this_should_be_an_error };
  },

  // Works but relies on you to correctly defining state
  reducer3: (state: MyState, action: MyAction) => {
    return { hello: action.say };
  }
}
```

Since each function will take a subtype of `IAction` as its `action` parameter (in this case `MyAction`), I must declare its type in the callback parameter. But once I declare its type, I lost the type of `state` and I must declare it. When I have dozens of callbacks and a real state name like `DataImportMappingState` for every callback, this is quite annoying.

Comment: AFAIK, the type inferred from the value can widen the type declared, although it is very counter-intuitive (so maybe there's something I'm missing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inference of `a` and `b` comes from *contextual typing*. Previously, parameters were only contextually typed if *all* parameters were unannotated.

[This behavior has changed in the latest build of the TypeScript compiler](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11673) because it seemed to be unintuitive. Now contextual typing will apply to all parameters which don't have explicit type annotations.

Comment: I swear you are robot. Thanks again Ryan, I will accept in 9 minutes when SO lets me. :)